# How to handle number of threads increasing linearly with number of topics in streaming pull?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Python script that takes a list of topics from the user and listens for events published to any of those topics. When an event is received, the script executes a specified action, such as invoking a shell command.

To listen for events, I created a streaming pull subscription for each topic using a thread pool. The thread pool has a maximum number of workers equal to the number of topics.
Code snippet:

```
topics = ["topic1", "topic2", ...]
consumer_pool = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(topics))
```

I also created a separate thread pool to handle the received events and execute the specified actions. This thread pool can have a different maximum number of workers, as specified by the user.
Code Snippet:

```
event_processing_limit = 10 # To be provided by user.
executor_pool = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=event_processing_limit)
```

I cannot use any other approach, such as push-based subscriptions or controlling the maximum number of workers in the thread pool that listens for events, because I need to listen for events from all topics in real time. Additionally, I cannot create push subscriptions because this would require creating a publicly accessible server, which I want to avoid for security reasons.

Is there a better way to do this, so that the number of threads does not increase linearly with the number of topics?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of problem faced by any web server: requests come in for different resources, and each request has to be handled quickly.  Creating a thread for each resource would be hopeless.  I think you should consider using a single point of entry for the requests, and dispatch the events to a small number of worker threads.  You can find examples in the Python standard library and also, I'm sure, on many web sites.  BTW, you will never achieve perfect real-time performance - you can try to come close, depending on your volume of requests and available computing power.

Comment: Just to add, I'm using [this python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.futures.StreamingPullFuture) which says that:

This future is resolved when the process is stopped (via cancel) or if it encounters an unrecoverable. The problem with one-consumer-thread-polling-a-subset-of-topics kind of approach is that calling .result() will cause the calling thread to block indefinitely.

I'll try to find an example, but if you have some examples handy that I can follow, could you please share it here? It would be of great help :)

Comment: Also, I think what you're suggesting can be possible via push based subscription but we want to avoid creating and exposing a public server endpoint for subscriptions. I have this python script running on multiple hosts, so creating/exposing endpoints on each host seems infeasible.

Comment: If calling `result` blocks the thread, then don't do that.  I'm not familiar with this package but I see that a function add_done_callback is available.  That might be a solution.  I have used the standard  asyncio package and it would work for this because you can `await future.result()` and the thread is not blocked.  Also in the standard library, there is the function `concurrent.futures.as_completed`, which yields results as fast as they become available.  Also check out `concurrent.futures.wait`.